# CSS Trick: make images load horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: html, css, image

I'm looking for a clever trick-like solution or hack to make images that usually load from top to bottom load from left to right?

Is there a way of doing this?

- My thoughts so far: Use images that are rotated 90° (in Photoshop or something) and use css transformations to rotate it back to normal and mask it or something. :) So far this doesn't lead to anything, but maybe somebody here has a hack or trick in doing this?

so to be clear, I'm talking about this simple thing that is probably not simple at all and probably not even possible.

[image]

---

Update: Well I don't know where to start … this is a sample fiddle with a large image that should load a while: http://jsfiddle.net/cfpqw9Lc/

```
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-inner">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0j0g2N1T2w3X0I3Y3Y3Z/dsc_2107.jpg" alt="Large Cat Image"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like your initial solution should work.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Please post your attempts so far and explain what did not work with those.

Comment: interesting... make a fiddle with your first thought if you can

Comment: So, similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/k01yh8bL/

Comment: @Ted I posted a fiddle. Didn't know where to start exactly.

Comment: @JosephMarikle of course the image should be regular to watch, so not rotated in the end. I just rotated the image in order to follow my thoughts, but I don't know if this would make a difference.

Comment: @matt That's a codec difference.  Some images can be interlaced to load in chunks rather than line by line, but this is not a styling preference.  It's how the image was encoded.  If you're open to serverside solutions, you could find a server based image manipulation program that rotates the images 90deg. and then implement this trick, but otherwise, I can't see it happening in just client side languages.  Even with canvas, it would have to load the image first before painting it and that would end up just being cosmetic loading to the detriment of the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could use absolute positioning and CSS animations to get a pure CSS "hack." Basically, the idea is that you're covering the image with a `div` and then animating that `div` off of the image, making appear as if it's loading from the side.

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
  <img src="whatever.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-animation: slider linear 10s;
  animation: slider linear 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider {
  from {width: 500px;}
  to {width: 0px;}
}

@keyframes slider {
  from {width: 500px;}
  to {width: 0px;}
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74c983wr/

EDIT: Changed the direction of the slide by using relative positioning and `right:0`

Now, the thing is, these images are still loading from top to bottom and will need to be fully loaded before running your animation, so this doesn't actually change that. All it does is give the user the impression that the images are being loaded in such a way.

Also, This will only work with a solid background, but you could probably use some z-index trickery to slide the image itself in, rather than sliding a cover off of it.